# JMeter master and slaves

Tags: java, jmeter, distributed-computing

The setup I currently have is one master and one slave. But I only use the slave to execute the test plan. But can I use the Master aswell and how do I do this?

One labtop has more power then the other, can i specify different amount of threads for both labtops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simple just started a server on the master and used my ip and then i used both labtops. Easy enough ;)